# Nodal and mesh analysis solution check

Tags: current, nodal-analysis, mesh-analysis

Is there any way, when doing nodal analysis or mesh analysis of circuit to check whether the final solution is correct except for doing both of them?

Comment: Use a simulation tool. They are free and quick. Or, ask for the result to be checked on this site but, show your workings.

Comment: @Andyaka that is good way to approach my question, but what if you are writing an exam and need to check it so none of the solutions provided by you can actually be used?

Comment: If none of the solutions I provide can actually be used then I cannot possibly provide a valid answer to your question.

Comment: @Filip Tell is what's really going on, please. Your comment appears to significantly modify your question.